# Get CloudPage URL via the API

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

Has anyone found a way to get a CloudPage URL via the API? I can get the asset collection as listed here,

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/content-api.htm

but no where in the returned data can I find the cloudpage URL or even a portion of the url, so that I could construct the full URL myself.

EDIT: I should mention that when I say via API, I'm not referring to AMPScript or SSJS. Ideally, I Need to be able to get this without accessing the SFMC UI.

I suppose if SSJS can do it I can first create the SSJS, create and invoke an automation which can maybe populate it to a newly created DE that I can read, but that seems a bit like overkill.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible using the API. I've tested several ways around it without success. SFMC use an internal endpoint to get this kind of data: /internal/v1/cloudpages.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a way to do this - however it could be a security vulnerability.

The [CloudPagesURL()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) function requires a SubscriberKey value to render; since it's generation a QueryString (qs) value for that specific subscriber.
There is a feature/bug that you can exploit to create your own micro endpoint to render these Subscriber-Specific links.

Below is how to solve your use case:

1. Create a JSON "Code Resource" in Cloud Pages
2. Put the following code in the JSON Cloud Page: `%%=CloudPagesURL(xxxx)=%%`
3. Save & Publish the Cloud Page
4. Click on the URL Link provided when you publish the page. Edit the URL and add `?sk=#SubscriberKey#` (where "#SubscriberKey#" is the SubscriberKey you are rendering the cloud page for) to the end of the URL. The final URL should look something like this:

> https://cloudpage.exacttarget.example.com/myCloudPageName?sk=Tester_1234567

The content of the page will be full URL target of your CloudPagesURL() function, including the subscriber-specific "qs" value at the end.

You can convert this into a JSON-compliant response by adding some structure to the response. For example:

`{"SubscriberPage":"%%=CloudPagesURL(xxxx)=%%"}`

With the above structure you can use a HTTPGET request (remember to include gzip headers) to return this JSON payload for your use outside of the platform.

Again, use this at your own risk - it's effectively a back door to impersonate any subscriber's view of a CloudPage "as if they had clicked a link from an email".

Comment: thanks for the answer. It's not quite what I'm looking for as I'm trying to do this without using the UI. I could potentially be in hundreds of accounts and won't have the option to follow the workflow you described, but it is a great suggestion